# Continuity implies the intermediate value property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

How can someone prove that continuity implies the intermediate value property?

P.S.: If $I$ is an interval, and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we say that $f$ has the intermediate value property (IVP) iff whenever $a<b$ are points in $I$ and $f(a)\leq c\leq f(b)$, there is a $d$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(d)=c$.

Comment: Thats the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem),

Comment: Functions, not necessarily continuous, that have this property are also known as Darboux functions. Examples include the derivatives of functions that are differentiable everywhere (even if they're not continuously differentiable).

Comment: I have given proofs of intermediate value theorem for continuous function in this post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-intermediate-value-theorem.html You can see that each proof uses a different version of completeness property of real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: This theorem can be proven using an epsilon/delta approach, given the [completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(order_theory)) property of the real numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This follows from the fact that [the image of a connected space under a continuous map is again connected.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Connected_Space_is_Connected)

Suppose there were some point $a \in f(I)$ so that that there were no $x$ sub that $f(x)=a.$ by the extreme value theorem, $a$ is on the interior of $f(I)$ and hence $f(I)$ would be the disjoint union of two open sets $\{x \in I \mid f(x)<a\}$ and $\{x \in I \mid f(x)>a\}$ in the sub space topology, a contradiction.

This specialization of the aforementioned fact is sometimes called the intermediate value theorem for calculus.

Comment: No need to appeal to the extreme value theorem here. All we need to do is show that the only connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals, and then $f(I)$ must be an interval and must contain every value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

Comment: That's true as well. I'm not convinced that this is easier to prove than the extreme value theorem, but you are fully correct.

Comment: See the Necessary Condition part of the proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Real_Numbers_is_Interval_iff_Connected).

Comment: Oh, I see your point. I'm on my phone, so I cannot edit right now, but yes. I agree

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $f(a) = f(b)$, then $c = f(a) = f(b)$, so $c$ can be chosen as $a$ or $b$. Otherwise $f(a) \neq f(b)$, and without loss of generality, $f(a) < f(b)$ (otherwise consider $-f$).

Let $S = \lbrace x \in [a, b] : f(x) \le c\rbrace$. Note that $a \in S$ and $S$ is bounded (above), so it has a supremum $p$. For all points $x \in (p, b]$, we have $x \notin S$, so $f(x) > c$. Therefore, using the continuity of $f$,

$$f(p) = \lim_{x\rightarrow p} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow p^+} f(x) \ge c.$$

On the other hand, since $p$ is the supremum of $S$, there must be a sequence $x_n \in S$ (i.e. such that $f(x_n) \le c$) such that $x_n \rightarrow p$. Therefore, by the continuity of $f$,

$$f(p) = f\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) \le c.$$

Putting together, $f(p) = c$, as required.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on the logical framework you're using.

In [smooth infinitesimal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis) (which uses intuitionistic logic rather than classical logic), every function is continuous, and the intermediate value theorem fails!

Comment: Why the IVT fails there?

Comment: @AngghaNugraha I don't know!